# How to change paperclip attachment path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

So, i've got a file which is processed after upload in a certain way. After that processing it should be moved to another folder. I did it with help of FileUtils.mv (since i didn't find any appropriate methods in paperclip documentation), but the thing is, .path of attachment left the same, so i'm getting an error when i'm trying to reach the file. I also tried to change path like in this guide https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Changing-attachment-:path but it didn't work and i've got some errors instead:

```
[paperclip] Trying to link /app/public/uploads/boxroom/development/90/original/90 to /tmp/8613985ec49eb8f757ae6439e879bb2a20201124-1-99na5g
[paperclip] Link failed with Invalid cross-device link @ rb_file_s_link - (/app/public/uploads/boxroom/development/90/original/90, /tmp/8613985ec49eb8f757ae6439e879bb2a20201124-1-99na5g); copying link /app/public/uploads/boxroom/development/90/original/90 to /tmp/8613985ec49eb8f757ae6439e879bb2a20201124-1-99na5g
Command :: file -b --mime '/app/public/uploads/boxroom/development/90/original/90'
[paperclip] Trying to link /tmp/8613985ec49eb8f757ae6439e879bb2a20201124-1-99na5g to /tmp/8613985ec49eb8f757ae6439e879bb2a20201124-1-1bzxm31
```

considering that source path is "/app/public/tmp_uploads/boxroom/development/90/original/90" and destination path - "/app/public/uploads/boxroom/development/90/original/90", can someone tell me how to change .path of the attachment? Or probably another way to move it to another folder?

Comment: Could you show some code of yours?

Comment: Did you ever figure out this error?

Comment: @Colto
If you are still interested - kind of yes. I've implement a new field for File's model - temporary_saved, it is works like a switch for has_attached_file inside model. In general, it works like this:
has_attached_file :attachment,
                      :path => lambda {|attachment| ":rails_root/public/#{'tmp_' if attachment.instance.temporary_saved}uploads/boxroom/:rails_env/:id/:style/:id" }

Comment: Thanks! I actually found that this is due to the permissions around setting up a symlink - so instead paperclip rescues from the symlink and creates an actual tmp copy of the file. Here is the issue/PR from Github https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/pull/2540